# Javascript array filtering and mapping

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, mapping

I keep asking the same question in terms of react and not getting a clear answer, so ive decided to attempt to extrapolate conceptually what i want to do and see if i cant get some answers on how i can proceed in react.

```
filters= ["Bill Johnson", "hasStartDocs"]
mappedArray = 
[
  {
  name:'Larry', 
  docs:{
   startDocs:[{...}]
   },
  workers:{
  sales:["Bill Johnson"]
  }  
]
```

So if filter[i] has a space{' '} check all arrays under workers for strings like filter[i] and then map
filteredMappedArray based on that

if filter[i] does not have a space create a new string slicing the first 3 chars of the string making the first letter of that new string lower case (thatString = "startDocs") eval(resoStatus.${thatString}.length > 0) then map filteredMappedArray like that.

so after that for every instance of [i] you would have a unique map. so if someone clicked 5 filters there would be a filteredMappedArray for each which i guess you would .concat() and .reduce() if they have the same _id.

I dont need someone to help with the string manipulation. I need a nudge in the right direction on how to utilize both filters [] and mappedArray [] to create 1 filteredMappedArray. please and thank you.

```
for(i=0,i<filters.length,i++){
filters.map(filter => filter.includes(' ') //map mappedArray based on rules above)
filters.map(filter => filter.includes(/^has/ //map mappedArray based on rules above)
}
```

this gives you

```
[filteredMappedArray1]
[filteredMappedArray2]

bigArray = filteredMappedArray1.concat(filteredMappedArray2)

smallArray = bigArray.forEach(map //if the map is unique delete it if the map isnt unique keep it but remove all the duplicates)
```

Comment: You want help writing a function to take those two arrays you've provided, and turn them into a different array, or arrays, right? So what should the output look like?

Comment: it would be one array of mappedArray objects

Comment: *"then if filters.length is > 0 && both filter conditions are met compare both filtered arrays and only show the values that are ==="* I'm sorry, you lost me there...? (Answering @TKoL's question will probably help, as will a more complete example of your input -- for instance, at least one entry that *doesn't* match either filter, an entry that matches just one of them, etc.)

Comment: @MickeyGray - "Show, don't tell." :-)

Comment: so basically if there is both types of strings in the array or multiple strings of any kind in the array the resulting mapped array has to get smaller not bigger.

Comment: So you want to apply a set of filters (`filters`) and include only results that match at least one of them (doesn't matter which one)? What's the "mapping" part of the question? You've said it's about "filtering and mapping."

Comment: i updated my thinking so basically create a map for every filter then concat and reduce those arrays for like values.

Comment: Can you please add the expected output (code) so we know what you mean exactly?

Answer (score 1):

As best as I can make out, you aren't doing any mapping, just filtering the `mappedArray` to limit it to entries that match at least one filter in `filters`.

If so, here's how to do that (see comments) provided you don't have lots more filters than you have entries in `mappedArray` (if you did, you'd structure it differently, but that seems unlikely to me):

```
// The `length` check prevents filtering if there are no filters; that's usually how people
// implement filters, but remove it if that's not right in your case
const filteredArray = filters.length === 0 ? mappedArray : mappedArray.filter(entry => {
    // `some` returns `true` if the callback returns a truthy value (and
    // stops loopihng); it returns `false` if it reaches the end of the
    // array without the callback rturning a truthy value. So basically
    // this is saying "return true if any filter matches."
    return filters.some(filter => {
        if (filter.includes(" ")) {
            // Check `workers` arrays
            for (const array of Object.values(entry.workers)) {
                if (array.includes(filter)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Check `docs` for at least one entry for the given type
            const key = /*...strip leading three, change case of fourth...*/;
            const array = entry.docs.key];
            if (array && array.length > 0) { // There's at least one entry
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: " for (const array of Object.values(entry.workers))" is most of what i needed thanks.

Comment: I guess then i could run something like this in state and return just those results instead of trying to do that on the search itself.